# printf's missing binary format specifiers: `%b` and `%B`

Tags: c, type-conversion, printf, glibc

I'm using an Ubuntu 22.04 for some software development, and working with binary data. I recently found [this announcement for `glibc` ver 2.35](https://web.archive.org/web/20221016003354/https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2022-February/136040.html); it states that ver 2.35 incorporates the *binary conversion format specifiers* `%b` and `%B`:

> - printf-family functions now support the %b format for output of
>   integers in binary, as specified in draft ISO C2X, and the %B variant
>   of that format recommended by draft ISO C2X.

I have checked my `glibc` version as follows, but I'm not sure this is the authoritative way to get this information:

```bash
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
```

##### It *appears* I can use the binary format specifiers `%b` and `%B`, but...

I've installed the [Raspberry Pi C SDK](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/c_sdk.html) about a month ago on this Ubuntu for a micro-controller project. I've used the binary format specifiers `%b` and `%B` in `printf` as follows:

```
    printf("\n  binary values stored in rcvdata[0]: %#b \n", rcvdata[0]);
    printf("  binary values stored in rcvdata[1]: %#b \n", rcvdata[1]);
```

The code compiles on the Pico without error or warning, and the output to my serial terminal (`minicom` 2.8) is as follows:

```
  binary values stored in rcvdata[0]: 0b11111111 
  binary values stored in rcvdata[1]: 0b11011000
```

So yeah - I can use the binary format specifiers in my RPi Pico C SDK development environment.

But then I tried to use similar `printf` statements for a small program I compiled with `gcc` to run on Ubuntu. It runs, but gives me 2 warnings for each usage:

##### The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char data_char = 0x41;
    unsigned char u_data_char = 8;
    int int_val = -39;

    printf("\nSome experiments:");
    printf("\nvalue of data_char: %#b", data_char);
    printf("\nvalue of u_data_char: %#b", u_data_char);
    printf("\nvalue of int_val: %#10b", int_val);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

##### Compilation output (partial):

```
$ gcc -o printf_binary_3, printf_binary_3.c
printf_binary_3.c: In function ‘main’:
printf_binary_3.c:10:37: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘b’ in format [-Wformat=]
   10 |     printf("\nvalue of data_char: %#b", data_char);
      |                                     ^
printf_binary_3.c:10:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
   10 |     printf("\nvalue of data_char: %#b", data_char);
```

##### The execution result:

```bash
$ ./printf_binary_3

Some experiments:
value of data_char: 0b1000001
value of u_data_char: 0b1000
value of int_val: 0b11111111111111111111111111011001
```

I don't know what to make of this:

- Why does `gcc` yield warnings & state `unknown conversion type character ‘b’` ??
- I'd **guess** the warning `[-Wformat-extra-args]` is the result of failure to recognize `%b` as a legitimate format specifier??

Finally - can anyone explain why I get what appears to be valid results when the compiler says the format specifier I used doesn't exist, and how to fix this?

And this may be useful information: [I learned during this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446354/why-is-man-3-printf-almost-one-year-behind-glibc-ver-2-35) that the documentation for the binary specifiers is not complete as of this writing.

Comment: It seems the version of GCC that you use just doesn't know about the binary specifier. And while a compiler might replace some function with other more optimized built-in function, that probably doesn't happen for `printf` and the library version uses it, which allows the binary specifier. Unlike the C++ standard library which it often tightly coupled with the compiler, there's no such tight coupling between the C compiler and the C libraries.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%b` instead of `%#b`?

Comment: gcc 12 lets the code compile but printf doesn't seem what to do with `%b` and `%#b` (I tried on x86 Linux). So I'm guessing it isn't using a modern enough library.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Supposedly `%#b` will print a `0b` prefix but I haven't checked the C23 draft.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not sure I understand what you're saying... if `glibc` has `%b` format specifier, and `printf` is part of `glibc`, how can `gcc` ignore that?

Comment: Glibc uses a special GCC-specific attribute for `printf` to let the compiler check the format string (if possible) (see the `format` [common function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)). If your compiler isn't new enough it will not recognize `%b`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: So what is "new enough"? `glibc` ver 2.35 was release nearly a year ago - I'm still missing something I guess  - after nearly a year, it's not recognized by the compiler, and not included in the standar `man` documentation. Is this typical?

Comment: It's the *compiler* that doesn't support the `%b` format specifier. Or rather, it doesn't recognize it as valid when it does the compile-time checking. What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0`.  I guess you're probably correct, but **I would have thought** that a compiler would almost have to rely on data from its core libraries in making such a decision. As you said, "tight coupling"...

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the discrepancy in your results is that the [Raspberry Pi C SDK](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/c_sdk.html) uses a different C library than the one on your Ubuntu system. Specifically, the [`picolibc`](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc) library is used by the SDK for code compiled for a Pico target system. This would explain why you get no errors or warnings when the target is a Pico.

OTOH, `glibc` is the C library used for compilations targeted for Ubuntu. This is a *bit of a guess*, but I can imagine that since the first version of `glibc` to support the `%b` format was 2.35 (the version on your Ubuntu system), there was some *unsettled business* between `gcc` and `glibc` that resulted in a *warning*. I say this because earlier versions of `glibc` (e.g. ver 2.31) and `gcc` (ver 10.2.1) produced an **error** instead of a **warning** upon seeing the `%b` conversion in `printf`, **and** compile without error or warning w/ `glibc` ver 2.36 and `gcc` ver 12.2.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry toolkit uses a different C compiler and C library, and seems to support the `%b` format at runtime (binary output) and compiler time (no warning).

Conversely, on the Ubuntu host, your C library supports the `%b` format (including the `#` option) as shown on the output, but the C compiler does not and reports a compile time warning.

The **gcc** warnings for `printf` and `scanf` argument consistency are produced at compile time by the compiler built-in analyser. The compiler does not use the C library for this so it may report a problem where the C library does support an extended format.

This inconsistency should be fixed with a more recent version of gcc, so you should either upgrade your system or install a more recent version of gcc manually.  You can also check the behavior of clang.

You can disable these warnings, but they are very useful to avoid stupid mistakes, so you should do this on a case by case basis with pragmas.